# SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Tags: c, winapi, device-driver, wdk

I used `SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail` to retrive the details of the driver. I used the following code fragment for this. But each time I execute my exe I am getting  `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`. How to solve this?

> SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, &drvInfoData,
>                                         &drvInfoDetail, sizeof(drvInfoDetail), NULL);

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read Microsoft's explanation of why the [SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.  Second, write code to call it twice.

Call SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail the first time with a pointer to a DWORD variable where you will find out how many bytes you need.  Allocate memory for a sufficiently large variable and call SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail again.

Comment: +1 This answer is correct.  The OP should make note of this technique of calling a function twice (first to get the required buffer size and then a second time to get the actual data) because it's very common in the Win32 API.  His first call should pass a buffer size of zero and expect the insufficient buffer error and the required buffer size to be returned.